# dpkg returns error 10 when processing package php5-common

Tags: dpkg

I'm having trouble installing php in 13.04. Seems like the package manager can't (re)configure the php package. I already tried purging every php* package, removing the cache files in /var/cache/aptbut and other solutions I've found but nothing seems to work. Here's the error output:

```
$ sudo dpkg --debug=12 --configure -a                                              
Setting up php5-common (5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/php5-common.postinst ( configure  )
dpkg: error processing php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cgi:
 php5-cgi depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-cgi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-fpm:
 php5-fpm depends on php5-common (= 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing php5-fpm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 php5-cli
 php5-cgi
 php5-fpm
```

`sudo apt-get install -f`  `sudo apt-get install php5-common php5` they all return the same error. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: @Braiam alright. Done.

Comment: exactly same problem here.

Comment: Can you please move the question instead of closing it? Google still sends us here!